# Make a control member of a list while it's created in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

So, I make a control in xaml

```
<Button x:Name="cancelOptionButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="15" Height="15"
                Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" BorderBrush="Black" Foreground="Black" Margin="3,3,0,0" Click="optionsButton_Click_1">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Cancel_Icon.png" />
            </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

In my code behind I have this:

```
private List<Control> controlList = new List<Control>();
```

I can ofcourse do this in my code behind:

```
controlList.Add(cancelOptionButton);
```

But is there a way to do it in xaml where I am creating the control?

I am either searching for the wrong thing in google or what I am asking is preposterous :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a way to do it in xaml where I am creating the control?

No, you can't add the control that you create in the XAML markup to the list field without first getting a reference to the field and call `Add` on it programmatically.

XAML is a *markup* language. It's not supposed to be used like a progamming language.

You may be able to add a control to a collection dependency property of another control but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks mate for the quick answer. So it was preposterous after all.